# Javascript - Override a digit while writing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm dealing with an issue while i'm formatting an input field with jQuery/javascript that could store just numbers.
It is in format: **12345,xy** (MaxDecimalNumber=2)

The requirement is that, when I insert the decimal part, I have to override the existing xy.

In other words, when I want to insert the first decimal digit(the caret is just after the comma), and I insert 'z', the number should become **12345,zy**, and not 12345,zx as actually does.

I already tried in this way:

```
$( "#my_field" ).keyup(function(e) {
    var comma = $("#my_field").val().indexOf(',');      
    var value= $("#my_field").val();
    var caret = doGetCaretPosition(this); //get caret position

    //I'm changing the decimal part
    if(caret>comma){
        var oldvalue = value.split(',');
        alert('oldvalue[1]='+oldvalue[1]);//oldvalue[1] already contain the digit pressed and not the old one

       //inserting the first decimal digit
        if(caret == value.length-1){
                var newdigit = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);//new digit inserted
                var olddigit = oldvalue[1].charAt(0);//it already has the new one
                var newvalue = value.replace(olddigit, newdigit);
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not able to get the old value...

Does someone have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Thanks Zord, now I'm able to substitute digit, but I have a strange behavior of caret...When change the first decimal digit, the caret goes at the end of the field. If I try to set the caret position, it incredibly duplicate the digit pressed right now!

This is what I wrote:

```
    $("#field").keydown(function(e){        
        var comma = $("#field").val().indexOf(',');
        var caret = doGetCaretPosition(this);
        if(caret>comma && ((e.keyCode>=49 && e.keyCode<=57) || (e.keyCode>=97 &&     e.keyCode<=105))){
            var dimDecPart = value.split(',');
            var decPart = dimDecPart[1];
            var lastvalue = decPart.charAt(1);
            var newvalue = "";
            if(caret < $("#field").val().length-1){
                var valinserted = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
                newvalue = value.substring(0,caret)+ valinserted + lastvalue;
                $('#field').autoNumeric('set', newvalue);
                $('#field').caret(comma+1);
            }
        }

    });
```

Any idea? Just to precise that on this field I'm using autonumeric plugin.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To understand, when you have `12345,xy`, it becomes `12345,zy`. And if I want to override with t, it becomes `12345,ty` right ?

Comment: No, actually I'm not able to override, so when I have "12345,xy", it becomes "12345,zx", but should become 12345,zy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `keyup` event triggered, the old value is already overwritten. If you want the old value, you could query it in the `keydown` or `keypress` event.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8r0wobnx/).

Comment: Thanks Zord, now I'm able to substitute digit, but I have a strange behavior of caret...When change the first decimal digit, the caret goes at the end of the field. If I try to set the caret position, it incredibly duplicate the digit pressed right now! Any idea? Just to precise that on this field I'm using autonumeric plugin

Comment: The caret works normally in the fiddle, but I can imagine that another keypress plugin on the same field causes problems. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with autonumeric.

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer. It solved your original problem. And it seems you don't get new answers to the autoNumeric part.

Comment: You are right, it works correctly. I just had to modify the plugin js

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var newValue = $("#my_field").val().replace(/x/, "z");

$("#my_field").val(newValue);
```